# Can a function nontrivially have this uniform zero-integral property?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am looking for a function $f:[0\;\pmb,\;1]\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that$$\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm dx=0\quad\text{for all }a,b\in[0\;\pmb,\;1].$$

Clearly such a function cannot be Riemann-integrable. But is there one under a more-general (e.g. Lebesgue) type of integration? The more I look at it, the more I doubt it. But I can't prove that there is no such function.

Comment: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then you must have $f(x)= 0$ ae.

Comment: @copper.hat : Thank you. Do you have a link to a proof of this?

Comment: It follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus applied to $t \mapsto \int_a^t  f(x)dx$.

Comment: @copper.hat : Sorry, I don't get it. The fundamental theorem of calculus applied to your function $t\mapsto0$ is not relevant. The (first or second) fundamental theorem cannot be applied to $f$ itself, because $f$ is not assumed to be Riemann-integrable or have an antiderivative. If it were so, the question would be trivial.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations

Comment: @copper.hat : I read that before I posted my comment.

Comment: The function I mentioned above is diferentiable ae. and so $f(x) = 0$ ae. which contradicts your assumption. Hence no such function can exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102042/discussion-between-john-bentin-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 0):

As copper.hat stated in a comment, if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and satisfies your condition, then $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

Now if $f$ additionally is continous, then $f(x)=0$ everywhere.

If on the other hand $f$ is not continuous, this doesn't need to be true. For example $f(1/2)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is Lebesgue integrable and satisfies your condition.

Comment: (1) Why is your first statement true? (2) Regarding the second statement: Yes, this is easily proved; but it doesn't address the question. (3) Your example (which is even Riemann-integrable) violates the condition that $f(x)$ is nowhere zero; please read the first line of the question.